# Excel formula time subtract time in text format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to subtract the time in text format
like: 10.51 - 2.15 (means 10hrs 51min - 2hrs 15min)

Now I using Min-Min and then convert to Hrs in text format, but have any wonderful code that I no need convert to Min? just Hrs-Hrs.
`=CONCATENATE(INT((textMin)/60),".",MOD(INT(textMin),60))`

I don't use time format or ":" because have a lot data to key in, number pad is good for key in much data.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can `SUBSTITUTE` the `.` with `:` and then subtract (quick way). There's probably a more robust solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways to approach this.

- Use Find and Replace to replace `.` with `:`, then use simple subtraction
- leave the data as you input it and use a formula to convert the decimals into time values

  ```
  =TIME(INT(A1),MOD(A1,1)*100,0)-TIME(INT(B1),MOD(B1,1)*100,0)
  ```

like here:

[image]

Or use

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",":")-SUBSTITUTE(B1,".",":")
```

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that replacing the `.` with `:` doesn't work if any of the "times" don't contain a period.

Comment: @BigBen No matter what I try, I cannot get the first formula to format as code. It only indents, but does not change font or background to grey. Can you give it a go?

Comment: Like that? Not sure if you want it indented under the bullet.

Comment: yep. that looks better,thanks. I don't mind the bullets. Just don't understand why it would not format properly. Tried repeatedly. Weird.

Comment: Something with lists and indents... triple backticks seems to do the trick normally.

Comment: @teylyn Hi, I deleted my answer just now that answer is still need change to time format. Btw have any way to output answer in text by your formula and no need change to time format?

Comment: @teylyn Hi, I found the formula for answer show in text format `=TEXT(TIME(INT(J3),MOD(J3,1)*100,0)-TIME(INT(I28),MOD(I28,1)*100,0),"[hh].mm")` Thanks ya!

Comment: If you just want to show the number formatted as a time, you don't need to wrap it in Text(). just format the cell as a time, or with the custom format `[hh]:mm`